# Java collection suggestion

Tags: java, android, performance, collections

I have a method as follows

```
  public List<List<CustomClass>> categorize(List<CustomClass> customClass){
        List<List<CustomClass>> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CustomClass customClassValue: customClass) {
              List<CustomClass> one = new ArrayList<>(), two = new ArrayList<>(), three = new ArrayList<>(), four = new ArrayList<>();
              switch (customClassValue.getAge()){
              case 1:
                    one.add(customClassValue);
                    break;
              case 2:
                    two.add(customClassValue);
                    break;
              case 3:
                    three.add(customClassValue);
                    break;
              case 4:
                    four.add(customClassValue);
                    break;
              }
              returnValue.add(one);
              returnValue.add(two);
              returnValue.add(three);
              returnValue.add(four);
        }
        return returnValue;
  }
```

Is there any alternative in java collection than usage of `List<List<CustomClass>>` in perspective of effectiveness and performance.

**Simply to describe what the function does:**

**Takes a input of List of custom objects and categorizes them based on a field in object and returns each category item separately.**

Comment: What about you custom class containing the `List`? Instead of `List<List<CustomClass>>` have `List<CustomClass>` and put the second `List` inside your custom class.

Comment: Simply to describe what the function does:

Takes a input of List of custom objects and categorizes them based on a field in object and returns each category item separately.

Comment: You are creating many lists, quarter of them with one `CustomClass` and the others are empty. Are you sure that this is what you are trying to do?

Comment: nope creation of list and adding them to returnValue will go outside for loop

Comment: @Venkat Not in the code you provided. Maybe you should provide the real code you are using if you want to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to sort things into buckets, my first instinct is to use `Map` instead of `List`. Dividing a `List<CustomClass>` into sublists based on age seems like a perfect time to use `Map<Integer, List<CustomClass>>`. Here's one way to do that:

```
    public Map<Integer, List<CustomClass>> categorize(List<CustomClass> customClass) {
        Map<Integer, List<CustomClass>> returnValue = new HashMap<>();

        for (CustomClass customClassValue: customClass) {
            List<CustomClass> sublist = returnValue.get(customClassValue.getAge());

            if (sublist == null) {
                sublist = new ArrayList<>();
                returnValue.put(customClassValue.getAge(), sublist);
            }

            sublist.add(customClassValue);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) is a cleaner version of a `Map<Key, List<Value>>` and Google's Guava has a nice implementation of it. It should solve the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public List<List<CustomClass>> categorize(List<CustomClass> customClass) {
    return customClass.stream()
        .filter(v -> v.getAge() >= 1 && v.getAge() <= 4)
        .collect(
            () -> IntStream.range(0, 4)
                .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<CustomClass>())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()),
            (list, v) -> list.get(v.getAge() - 1).add(v),
            (a, b) -> {});
}
```

Comment: thanks for the optimized code but i'm restricted in usage of java V1.7